# ES6 - Express4 : anyway to show up favicon on localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, ecmascript-6

using ***serve-favicon***(v2.3.2)/ ***node***(v7.4.0)/ ***express***(v4.14.0) with ***Typescript***(v2.1.5) and ES6, I am trying to get a favicon as usual:

In my **server.ts**

```
import * as favicon from "serve-favicon";
...
export class Server {
    public app: express.Application;
    public static bootstrap(): Server {...}
    constructor() {...}
    public config() {
         this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
         ...
         this.app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico")));
         ...
    }
    private routes {...}
 }
```

I inserted the myapp/public/favicon.ico image, nothing is showing on localhost:8080, is there anyway to show it up ?

***UPDATE***. app directory structure after transpiling TS to JS

```
  dist
    app
      |_ interfaces  (...)
      |_ models  (...)
      |_ public
      |    |_ favicon.ico
      |
      |_ routes (...)
      |_ schemas. (...)
      |_ test  (...)
      |_ views  (...)
      |_ route.js
      |_ server.js
```

Comment: What about `localhost:8080/public/favicon.ico` ? If it is `404`, then please share the directory structure of app.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico  request displays the icon in the browser page...
see app directory structure in question update..  thanks

Comment: Does your `html` page have link to favicon ?

Comment: no , I assumed that the request was automatic ..?